# Azure diagnostics in SDK 2.9 - Custom performance counters

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

I am trying to see if there is a way to read the custom performance counters listed in wadcfgx file. Is there a way to do this in a web role or worker role?

Comment: You want to read this information programmatically. Correct?

Comment: Oh yes! Previously i was using RoleInstanceDiagnosticManager. I was still using wadcfg to define them though. But now looks like it is depracated